copying and pasting cell contents (including new lines with alt+enter) separately for a column
I would like to copy and paste cell contents (which can includes new lines with alt+enter) respectively and separately (line-by-line) in a column to another column.
It is not certain where the range of cells will end. My aim is to sort cell content line by line with a loop (for/ do until) and then remove duplicate/repeating ones.
I used the below code for it but it does not work. There may be another method for looping, for/do until is not necessary.
    Sub Button7_Click()
    Dim a As Range, cell As Range, isect As Range
    Set a = Range("A1:A50")
    Set isect = Intersect(Target, a)
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    If isect Is Nothing Then 
    Exit sub
    Else 
    For Each cell in isect
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
    x = split (worksheets("sheet1").cell.value.vbLf)
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = x(i)
    Next i
    End if
    Next cell
    End if 
    End sub


What is Target in your code?

Should i use change(ByVal Target As Range) instead of buttonclick?

Why using an event if you need to process all records from A:A? Please, try the code I posted and send some feedback. Now I close my laptop and leave my office...

Please, try the next way. It uses arrays and it should be very fast, even for huge range. It processes all cells having content from "A:A":
Sub splitAndCopyInAnotherColumn()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * 15, 1 To 1)
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then
            arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 1), vbLf)
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrSpl)
                k = k + 1
                arrFin(k, 1) = arrSpl(j)
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
   If k > 0 Then
    ws.Range("B:B").ClearContents
    ws.Range("B1").Resize(k, 1).Value2 = arrFin
   End If
End Sub


How can I adapt this code to paste string data into another sheet in the same workbook?

You should only change ws.Range("B1").Resize(k, 1).value2 = arrFin by replacing ws with Worksheets("needed sheet")...

If the cell contents are string? Which objects should i turn into string at the beginning?

I cannot get you... Everything separated  by vbLf will be returned starting from the top line. Practically, only strings are separated by end of lines. Am ai missing anything?

I mean that the code gives an error if the values ​​inside the cells are text. It only works if the values ​​are numbers. I have no idea about vbLf unfortunately. Is there a way to convert your code for the cells including string values? Thank you very much in advance.

@PYC When the code raises an error, not mentioning which error and showing the code line where it is raised is useless...  It should work on strings and numbers, too. If there is no vbLf separator it takes the whole cell content (string or number...).

I tried again and yes you are exactly right. I think the problem is that the code does not work in the data excel file I created with Data>Get Data>From Folder (I combined the data from several excel files). But as you said, the code works for all data. thank you very much for this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@PYC I do not have too much availability now... But, what is to be discussed? If you have a different issue than the actual question, the best idea would be to place another question and somebody else with more availability will help you to solve it. If you tag me (here) with the question link I will try helping when I will be less busy...

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78590511/22460101

@PYC OK, I  will try looking on it. I only hope what that you requir to be clear...
