conditional copy and paste line by line with vba
With the precious help of @FaneDuru, I could copy and paste cell contents (which can includes new lines with alt+enter) respectively and separately to another column in another sheet with the below code until i added bolded part into the code.
My aim is to sort cell content if there is ‘NONE’ string in the C column. But i receive error 1004 at this line.
Sub Sheet2_Button_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As 
Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

arr = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2
ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * 15, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
     If arr(i, 1) <> "" And **ws.Range(“C2:C”) = “NONE”** Then
         arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 1), vbLf)
         For j = 0 To UBound(arrSpl)
             k = k + 1
             arrFin(k, 1) = arrSpl(j)
         Next j
     End If
Next i
If k > 0 Then
 Worksheets(sheet1).Range("B:B").ClearContents
 Worksheets(sheet1).Range("B1").Resize(k, 1).Value2 = arrFin
End If
End Sub


So, understanding that you need to place in the output cells from A:A only if in C:C column the string "None" exists, would it be correct?

Yes, that's exactly it.

OK, I will prepare an answer. I do not remember in which column of the other sheet you wanted returning... If no rapid answer, I will use the same B:B column. It would be easy to adapt it for any column, I think.

Please, try the next adapted code. Do not forget to use your real destination sheet name:
Sub splitAndCopyInAnotherColumn()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set wDest = Worksheets("your destination sheet name") 'use here the CORRECT existing destination sheet name
   lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = ws.Range("A1:C" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * 15, 1 To 1)
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) <> "" And UCase(arr(i, 3)) = "NONE" Then
            arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 1), vbLf)
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrSpl)
                k = k + 1
                arrFin(k, 1) = arrSpl(j)
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
   If k > 0 Then
    wDest.Range("B:B").ClearContents
    wDest.Range("B1").Resize(k, 1).Value2 = arrFin
   End If
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
Edited:
I cannot stay too much near my laptop. So, since you do not clarify the sheets/column issue, I prepared another version processing column D:D if in C:C "NONE" exists and returning to the other sheet in "A1":
Sub splitAndCopyInAnotherColumnReversedSheets()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
   Const searchStr As String = "NONE" 'you can use here any string you need
   
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sayfa2"): Set wDest = Worksheets("Sayfa1")  'use here the CORRECT existing sheet
   lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column D:D
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary (able to keep only unique keys)
   arr = ws.Range("C1:D" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * 15, 1 To 1)
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 2) <> "" And UCase(arr(i, 1)) = searchStr Then
            arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 2), vbLf)
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrSpl)
                dict(arrSpl(j)) = "" 'create dictionary keys only for unique strings!
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
   If dict.Count > 0 Then
        wDest.Range("A:A").ClearContents 'clear all values in A:A
        wDest.Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
        wDest.Activate
   Else
      MsgBox "No any value in D:D containing """ & searchStr & """ in C:C exists..." 'message in case of no returned value
   End If
    
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub


I guess that it gave error 9 because I changed the column names. I made a change to move the data in column D on sheet 2 to column A on sheet 1 if there was 'NONE' in column 'C' on sheet2.

@PYC Then, you should only correctly named that second sheet when setting wDest and replaced B with D after If k > 0 Then... And on which code line is this error raised? If I correctly understood your comment... Sheet 1 and 2 are relative. Should I understand that you try processing Columns D and C of the second sheet and use as destination the first sheet, column A:A? I cannot get you... If there were other sheets and columns involved, why didn't you specify the ones you need?

Yes, i am trying to derive data from D column on sheet 2 according to string values in C column on sheet 2 and transfer data to A column on sheet1. As you mentioned, i replaced B with D after k>0, interestingly, although there is no error, the code does not work for some reason.

I thought I could easily adapt the code according to the columns Iam working on. Really sorry for my mistake.

@PYC As I tried suggesting sheets 1 and 2 are relative... And I mentioned (after the second code) that the sheet to be processed (columns D:D and C:C) would be ws and wDest must be the destination sheet, the one where to return (in "A1"). So, the second version (after Edited) should work, but **if you understand which sheet to be ws and the other one to be wDest...

Please don't wait for me, because I work slowly. You can reply whenever you are convenient. Thank you very much for your valuable help and time. I am still trying your codes.

The code does not give an error, but for some reason it keeps looping between these lines: If arr(i, 1) <> "" And UCase(arr(i, 2)) = "NONE" Then and Next i

But there is no rush, you can write whenever you are free and whenever you want to look at it. I'll be waiting for you, I'm here anyway.

@PYC It was a mistake in the second version. Column C:C is before D:D... I adapted the respective code part. Please, test it and give some feedback. I did not test the code and neither now I do not have the possibility to test it, but it should work, I think...

Should it be revised like this: arr = ws.Range("C1:D" & lastR).Value2 ?

@PYC It only looks nicer (more estetic...), but VBA does not care about this aspect. For instance, Debug.Print Range("D1:C10").address will return "C1:D10". Or arr = Range("D1:C10").value followed by Debug.print arr(1,1) will return the "C1" cell value. Should I understand that it still does not work? If so and nothing confidential in your workbook, please share it and I will send it back with the correct code. Now I am at home and I can test it. You can use a transfer site. For instance, here you can find such a site, free and easy to be used.

Or send it by by mail. My personal mail is in my profile...

I sent an e-mail to you. I wanted to write here in case it ended up in junk mail.

@PYC Now I am in vacation in a Greece island and here the internet is very week. It will take some time to have it received...

I wish a nice holiday.

@PYC I did not receive anything. Neither in Spam... Please, check the mail account where you tried sending... ivangu@yahoo.com

@PYC OK, I came back to the hotel and found the file. I can understand (now) that you need to keep only unique values. I will adapt the code using a Scripting Dictionary, able to keep only the unique keys as strings. I will post the new code in 5 - 6 minutes...

It is an incredibly perfect job. I very much appreciate your support. I would like to thank you wholeheartedly for not hesitating to help me even during your holiday. I wish your success continues growingly
